# Automatically renice on process start

Tags: linux, process-management

I have few steam games. Right now I `renice` them manually.

```
sudo renice -n -20 -p $(pgrep csgo_linux64)
```

Is there a way I can automatically do that (using systemd rules or something)?

Comment: Simplest way: Write a wrapper script to start them, rename the old program or modify PATH so it doesn't find it, always start with wrapper script.

Comment: `nice(1)`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use followed command:

```
systemctl edit --force --full name-of-your-service
```

Then edit the file that will open:

```ini
[name-of-your-service]

Nice=your-nice-value
```

Answer (score 1):

The following may have some security implications of which I'm unaware, but all of the suggestions could achieve an answer to the question.

I use [gamemoderun](https://github.com/FeralInteractive/gamemode) which is available on a lot of Linux distributions.  It can can perform a variety of tweeks relevant to games, including doing a **nice**.  For steam I change each game's *properties launch options* to be:

```
__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATION=1 gamemoderun %command%
```

To obtain the necessary permissions for nice/renice I have a **gamers** Linux/UNIX group. I add the following entries in /etc/security/limits.conf to set a default for limit for everyone via the **user** group, and then to allow anyone in the **gamer** group to renice by up to -6 but with a system hard limit of -10:

```
# limits for gamers group in /etc/security/limits.conf
# set default and max prio for users who are members of the gamer group
@user           -       nice    0
@gamer          soft    nice    -6
@gamer          hard    nice    -10
```

I put myself in the **gamers** group (this takes effect on a new login or via the newgrp command).

With these limits set gamemoderun can read and set a desired renice value from /home/myself/.config/gamemode.ini and apply it on game startup.

The one issue I have is that steam proton games seem to lose affinity with the command that started them and don't get the appropriate new limits.  One workaround for this issue is to start steam with gamemoderun so that all processes it starts will wind up with the same limits.

Another possibility would be to use [reniced](https://github.com/mmitch/reniced) or [schedtool](https://github.com/freequaos/schedtool) which, as I understand it, renice on the fly by matching processes attributes via periodic scans of the system.